# How to create a listable, memoized function

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, memoization

Suppose I have a known real constant $a$, and I want to calculate $f(n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(a-k)$. I know I could memoize this function

```
Clear[a, f];
a = 8;
f[0] = 1;
f[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n := f[n] = f[n - 1]*(a - n);
f[2]
?f
```

Results

```
42
Global`f 
f[0]=1 
f[1]=7 
f[2]=42
f[n_Integer]/;1<=n:=f[n]=f[n-1] (a-n)
```

But this function is not listable.

```
f[{1,2,3}]
```

> f[{1,2,3}]

Alternatively, I know I could make the function listable without memoizing

```
Clear[f];
f[n_Integer] := Times @@@ (a - Range[n]);
f[{1,2,3}]
```

> {7, 42, 210}

I've been trying to think of a good way of making it both memoized and  listable, and I came up with the following

```
Clear[f]
f[0] = 1;
f[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n := f[n] = f[n - 1]*(a - n);
f[n_List] := f /@ n;
```

Is there a better (as in more efficient) way to do this?

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, Listable]`

Comment: Are you looking for [`Pochhammer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pochhammer.html)? `Pochhammer[8 - #, #]&@Range@3 (* {7, 42, 210} *)`

Comment: Thanks for the help with SetAttributes, @Batracos. And yes! I should be using Pochhammer instead of re-creating it.